# How to select a group of entities according to a condition in a related OneToMany association?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Symfony4 and I have two entities `User` and `Car`.

A `Car` has a field `isRent` which is of type `bool` and further a database column `user_id` for the relation.

```php
class User
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Car", mappedBy="user")
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("ArrayCollection<ListRestAPI\Entity\Cars>")
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $cars;
```

```php
class Car
 {
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="cars")
     */
    private $user;
```

Now I'm trying to fetch all users who have cars rented.

My current query fetches all the users regardless of whether they have cars rented or not.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select()
    ->join('u.cars', 'c')
    ->andWhere(sprintf('%c.is_rent = :isRent', 'c'))
    ->setParameter('isRent', '1')
    ->groupBy('u.id')
    ->addOrderBy('u.id');
```

How can I fetch only `User` entities that have cars rented?

Comment: `->andWhere(sprintf('%c.is_rent = :isRent', 'c'))`? What is this `sprintf` for? Why would you do this?

Comment: Ah I was doing everything I could, saw this thing somewhere on the web, tried it...

Comment: Yeah I want to get users who have cars in rent

Comment: show all fields declired in php file for entity car, cause %c.is_rent probably should be changed to %c.isRent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing your `andWhere()` by this:

```
->having('c.isRent = 1')
```

Since you are using an integer in your query, no need to use bound parameters. You should also remove `setParameter()`.